# conditionally loading scripts on window.onresize

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I want to conditionally load some files (javascript and css) based on window size. I would like the files to be "swapped" on window resize, but also to be correctly loaded when the site first load. I am using Modernizr with the yepnope library to do so. However, the code only works on load, and not on resize. I checked the resize event using an alert, and it seems to trigger correctly, but the function only runs onlaod.When I resize the browser, it seems to flicker, as if it is trying to switch between the different files.

I am not very good at js, so I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="scripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script> 
<script>
function myLoader(){

    Modernizr.load([
      {
      load: [  

      'scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' 

      ]
    },
        {
            test: Modernizr.mq('(max-width:600px)'),
            yep: 
            [
                'css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css', 
                'css/custom.css',
                'scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js'
            ],
            nope:
            [
               'css/mystyle.css'
            ]
        }
    ]);
}

window.onresize = myLoader();
window.onload = myLoader();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to load different resources based on a device orientation?

Comment: no, just by widnow size. I want to load jquery Mobile (and all associated files0, if it is smaller than 600px, and a regular css if larger

Comment: so you're using jQuery Mobile for mobile website?

Comment: yes, that was the idea. Jquery mobile will style the mobile version, and regular css the larger version of the responsive site

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is your parenthesis

```
window.onresize = myLoader();
window.onload = myLoader();
```

What you are saying is set the value of `window.onresize` to the returned value on myLoader (which you aren't explicitly setting, so it is `undefined`)

What you *want* to do, is set it to the function *reference* `myLoader`

Consider this example

```
function hello() {
    return 'world'
}
```

`hello()` is equal to `world`, where as `hello` is equal to `function hello() {return 'world'}`. No parenthesis means return the function itself, parenthesis means evaluate the function and return its return value.

To fix your issue, simply drop

```
window.onresize = myLoader;
window.onload = myLoader;
```

Comment: thank you for your great explanation: it makes sense. Unfortunately, thought, even without parenthesis, it still only works on load (when I refresh the page) not onresize. Maybe it just can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid I think the issue’s a bit more fundamental than Patrick realised – he’s right about the parentheses though.

***tl;dr:*** Either consider having separate desktop and mobile sites, or try and architect your site such that all window sizes use the same stylesheets and scripts.

---

Here’s why what you tried doesn’t work.

Firstly, `Modernizr.load()` only loads things – it doesn’t unload them. So what you’ve got there will do something like this:

```
# page loads
if screen width <= 600px:
  load 'css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css'
  load 'css/custom.css'
  load 'scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js'
else:
  load 'css/mystyle.css'

# page is resized
if screen width <= 600px:
  load 'css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css'
  load 'css/custom.css'
  load 'scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js'
else:
  load 'css/mystyle.css'

# page is resized again
if screen width <= 600px:
  load 'css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css'
  load 'css/custom.css'
  load 'scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js'
else:
  load 'css/mystyle.css'

# etc
```

i.e. they’ll load on top of each other.

So if the screen was 320px on load, then a single resize event fired and it was then 800px wide, you’d have all 4 files loaded *together*. Both sets of styles would be present at once, and the jQuery Mobile JS would still be active even when the screen is wider than 600px.

When you resize the page by dragging the edge of a browser, it actually fires LOADS of resize events, so realistically you’ll probably actually have dozens of copies of each file loaded. The JS will have run several times, which could cause stability issues (because it only expects to be run once).

This probably isn’t what you want.

If you wanted it to *switch* between the two, you’d need to remove the previous CSS and JS when the screen resizes. But it’s really not that simple.

### CSS

CSS is declarative. The stylesheets in the DOM at any given time are “added” together into a single style tree, which is then applied to the DOM. This means that duplicate stylesheets probably don’t cause any problems (you’re just restating the same rules), but it’s certainly untidy. It also means if you *remove* a stylesheet, those styles would no longer be applied.

So you *could* do something like this:

```
function myLoader() {
  $('[href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css"]').remove();
  $('[href="css/custom.css"]').remove();
  $('[href="css/mystyle.css"]').remove();

  // then the rest
}
```

Removing any existing stylesheets before (potentially) loading others means you’ll only have the styles you expect in the DOM at any given time.

That’s just an example, though. It would be much more performant and flexible to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

### JS

JavaScript is a more complex one here. It’s procedural – when you execute JavaScript it changes the state of the page. It might define functions, add new elements to the DOM, set up event handlers, etc.

If you remove the script tag from the DOM, those state changes don’t magically become undone. In fact it would be pretty hard to reliably reverse the effect of a script. It’s kind of like stirring some cream into a Chicken Balti then finding you’ve got a lactose-intolerant person coming for dinner… it’s pretty hard to get it out again.

The only way to undo the effect of a script which has already executed is to refresh the page. Obviously this would be really annoying for a user, to lose their place in the page, have to wait for it to load again, etc.

## So…

You have 2 options.

1. Make both versions (narrow screens and wide screens) work with the same JS – so you load it once regardless (like you’re doing with jQuery). This either means making your wide screen version work with jQuery Mobile too, or making your narrow version work *without* jQuery Mobile. Note my comment above about using Media Queries to serve different styles to different screen sizes too.
2. Give up on the resizing action. How likely are users to resize the screen during the session? If your sites are different enough to require completely different styles and scripts, maybe you could just detect on page load then either send them to a “desktop” or “mobile” site then leave it like that for the rest of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Patrick and Stu for your very helpful answers!

Stu: I did notice the issue of CSS overlapping and not being able to "unload". You are also right on your proposed solutions. From a performance point of view, it makes sense to abandon the resize altogether. However, on a theoretical basis only, you could overcame the issue of styles overlapping once loaded (if it is only a question of css) by adding and removing special classes, and then modify your css  with those. Maybe not the most efficient or elegant solution, but it would be something like this:

```
<script src="scripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
         <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
      function myLoader(){
         Modernizr.load([
         {
              test: Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width:600px)'),
              yep:[
                'css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css', 
                'css/custom.css',
                'scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js'
               ],
               nope:[
               'css/mystyle.css'
               ],
               complete:function(){
                if(window.innerWidth<601){
                    $('body').removeClass('lrgScreen');
                    $('body').addClass('jqMobile');
                }else{
                  $('body').removeClass('jqMobile');
                  $('body').addClass('lrgScreen');
                }

               }
         }
         ]);
       }

      window.onresize = myLoader;
      window.onload = myLoader;
    </script>
```

Comment: Yep, that’s effectively what [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) seek to do (specifically for `min-width`/`max-width` style declarations. You can define all your styles together then declare that some should only be applicable to certain screen sizes – all in CSS, no JS needed.